# How can I run (start) a framebuffer application via SSH?

Tags: framebuffer

I am currently fiddling around with a RaspberryPi and a [TFT hat](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2097). It is connected to the RPi GPIO pins. The TFT screen itself is working and I see the normal Linux console on it. I fetched a quick pygame example and ran it successfully using:

```
SDL_FBDEV=/dev/fb1 python3 myapp.py
```

But my setup is a bit fiddly, with the small PI and a separate keyboard attached to it. I would love to be able to `ssh` into the PI, do some experimentation and launch the application via the remote console.

However when I `ssh` into the PI and run the above command, it won't show anything as the graphics environment is not available in the `ssh` session. I tried running a tmux shell and attaching to that, but without success. Obviously using the `DISPLAY` variable won't work either as I'm not running X. I tried that anyway but it did not work.

The setup I imagine is having the PI sitting on the desk with the only cable attached to it being the power cable. Network would be done by WiFi. So I would have a small box on my desktop with a small TFT screen on it. Then I would like to connect to that box via `ssh` to deploy the application and run it in that `ssh` shell. When running this I would like the application to show up on the small TFT screen on the PI.

The `ssh` client varies. If I use my laptop to connect that would be `OpenSSH` in likely the latest version of whatever is current in Arch Linux, and when using another PC that would be the OpenSSH client from Cygwin

Is there *any* way to start the application remotely such that it shows up on a selected framebuffer device?

Comment: One possible setup is using a serial cable.

Comment: Maybe this: https://github.com/ponty/framebuffer-vncserver ? (found via "remote framebuffer" online search).

Comment: @TomášPospíšek this looks promising. I'll give it a try tonight.

Comment: @TomášPospíšek this does not quite work. It only exposed the framebuffer via VNC, but I still cannot launch a framebuffer application via SSH

Comment: I'd imagine: 1. setup framebuffer -> VNC, 2. setup VNC to where you sit, 3. log in via ssh, start the application that displays onto that framebuffer. Which step is unworkable?

Comment: The problem happens after SSHing into the box. I get an error that the graphical system is not initialised. It looks I don't have access to graphics when SSHing in.

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify: Are you trying to display on a display that is attached to the PI, or to the device that has `ssh`ed to the pi? If the 2nd what is this device? What software do you use to `ssh` (your ssh client)?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Added some clarification

Comment: So what is the TFT connected to?

Comment: It's connected to the GPIO pins. I've added a link to the hat in the question.

Comment: The problem may be with VT switching. Put the Linux console on another terminal to check that. You may also try to connect a keyboard to the Pi and do Ctrl+Alt+F1..F10, or use the ``chvt`` tool through ssh.